# AutoSys job condition with success and delay

Tags: autosys

I have three jobs in a box job and want to schedule the three jobs to run one after another. 
job1, then job2 when job1 is in success, then job3 when job2 is in success. I also want to add a timing condition and have job2 wait 10 mins after job1 succeeded and similary for job3 to wait 10 mins after job2 succeeded. Currently I have this:

```
job2:
condition: s(job1)

job3: 
condition: s(job1) & s(job2)
```

I am not sure how to add the 10 mins delay.
Would something like this work?

```
condition: s(job1,00.10) & s(job2,00.10)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, lookback is not appropriate in this case.
I'd add a sleep job between job2 and job3

Answer (score 0):

I use a file watcher to achieve this. See the jil below which "Sleeps" for 30 seconds...

```
/* ----------------- T4useBJ_CHRIS_SLEEP_TEST ----------------- */ 

insert_job: T4useBJ_CHRIS_SLEEP_TEST   job_type: BOX 
owner: administrator
permission: gx,wx
date_conditions: 0
description: "Sleep test"
alarm_if_fail: 0



/* ----------------- T4useEXT_CHRIS_SLEEP_TEST ----------------- */ 

 insert_job: T4useEXT_CHRIS_SLEEP_TEST   job_type: CMD 
 box_name: T4useBJ_CHRIS_SLEEP_TEST
 command: copy nul D\:\hrbatch\test\sleep_test.txt /* use touch on UNIX */
 machine: trent4
 owner: administrator
 permission: gx,wx
 date_conditions: 0
 description: "Trigger File Watcher"
 std_out_file: "d:\hrbatch\Test\%AUTO_JOB_NAME%.%AUTORUN%.out"
 std_err_file: "d:\hrbatch\Test\%AUTO_JOB_NAME%.%AUTORUN%.err"
 alarm_if_fail: 0



/* ----------------- T4useFW_CHRIS_SLEEP_TEST ----------------- */ 

 insert_job: T4useFW_CHRIS_SLEEP_TEST   job_type: FW 
 box_name: T4useBJ_CHRIS_SLEEP_TEST
 machine: trent4
 owner: administrator
 permission: gx,wx
 date_conditions: 0
 condition: success(T4useEXT_CHRIS_SLEEP_TEST)
 description: "Look for sleep_test.txt file"
 alarm_if_fail: 0
 watch_file: "d:\hrbatch\test\sleep_test.txt"
 watch_interval: 30



/* ----------------- T4useDEL_CHRIS_SLEEP_TEST ----------------- */ 

 insert_job: T4useDEL_CHRIS_SLEEP_TEST   job_type: CMD 
 box_name: T4useBJ_CHRIS_SLEEP_TEST
 command: del D\:\hrbatch\test\sleep_test.txt
 machine: trent4
 owner: administrator
 permission: gx,wx
 date_conditions: 0
 condition: success(T4useFW_CHRIS_SLEEP_TEST)
 description: "Remove trigger file"
 std_out_file: "d:\hrbatch\Test\%AUTO_JOB_NAME%.%AUTORUN%.out"
 std_err_file: "d:\hrbatch\Test\%AUTO_JOB_NAME%.%AUTORUN%.err"
 alarm_if_fail: 0
```